# Flattening a tree in haskell using in-order traversal

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, inorder

I want to implement flattenning a tree using my foldTree function that I defined and in-order traversal.Which should return a list after flattening.

```
data Tree t = Leaf t
        | Tree (Tree t) t (Tree t)


foldTree :: (t1 -> t -> t1 -> t1) -> (t -> t1) -> Tree t -> t1
foldTree treeFn leafFn tree =
case tree of
  Leaf v -> leafFn v
  Tree leftTree q rightTree -> treeFn (foldTree treeFn leafFn leftTree) q (foldTree treeFn leafFn rightTree)


Input : foldTree (\t1 t t2->t1 + 5*t + t2) (\x->x+9) (Leaf 5)
Expected Output : 14

Input : foldTree (\t1 t t2->t1 + 3*t + t2) (\x->x+5) (Tree (Leaf 3) 2 (Leaf 4))
Expected Output : 23
```

I tried the following code but it uses recursion.I want to call foldTree from flattenTree to implement the flattening of tree instead of making a recursive call to flatTree.(Using foldTree functions in flattenTree).Can anyone help me on how to integrate it.

```
flatTree :: Tree a -> [a]
flatTree tree = 
case tree of
    Leaf v -> [v]
    Tree p v r -> (flatTree p) ++ [v] ++ (flatTree r) 

Input: flatTree (Tree (Leaf 5) 3 (Tree (Leaf 3) 2 (Leaf 4)))
Expected output : [5,3,3,2,4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the type of `foldTree`.

```
foldTree :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b
```

You can see that `b` is the result type of the catamorphism. `foldTree` works by folding each sub-tree to obtain a result `b` for each, then combining them using the folding function.

Since you want the result to be a flattened list of the tree's elements, let's set `b ~ [a]`.

```
foldTree :: ([a] -> a -> [a] -> [a]) -> (a -> [a]) -> Tree a -> [a]
```

So the second argument of `foldTree` should be something which injects a single element `a` into a list `[a]`, and the first should be one that combines two lists with an element to make a bigger list.

```
flatTree = foldTree (\xs x ys -> xs ++ x : ys) (\x -> [x])
```

---

Incidentally, GHC is able to write your `flatTree` function for you, just by looking at the structure of the type. `flatTree :: Tree a -> [a]` matches the type of [`toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList), which is part of the `Foldable` class. All you need to do is say the magic words, `deriving Foldable`, and GHC will spit out an instance of `Foldable`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree t = Leaf t
            | Tree (Tree t) t (Tree t)
            deriving Foldable

flatTree :: Tree a -> [a]
flatTree = toList
```

Because of the way the `Tree` constructor is laid out, `toList` will perform an in-order traversal. This can be varied by adjusting the definition of the `Tree` constructor.